# Custom annotation in TestNG Report for selenium Testing

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng, java-annotations

I have been using selenium webdriver to automate AUT. Unfortunately our system has lot of known bugs and Product is ok with them but the real problem is those test cases will fail in TestNG report and management will get a big list of failed testcases. So Management asked me to remove known issues from the test but my test manager is not  agreed to remove/disable them from test.

So what I am thinking is, create a custom annotation and have a field called bugNumber and based on the existence of the bug number I will create a report where test cases failed with known bug number will go down in the report and failed test cases without bugNumber will come on the top of the report. But I really don't know how to get those custom annotations to TestNG test-results.

Could you guys suggest me something please ?

Comment: and finally I found this    bugNumber=testResult.getMethod().getConstructorOrMethod().getMethod().getAnnotation(ReportingAnnotaton.class).bugNumber();

Comment: can you please elaborate on how you implemented this idea? Looking for similar solution. How does your report look like now?